# I want to implement a Job Scheduler

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I want to implement a Job Scheduler for the run a task for a given time and it should have an ability to set repeat period like every day, every week or every month. So how should I do it correctly?

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-jobscheduler-api-on-android-lollipop--cms-23562

Comment: I also want it to run pre-lollipop versions?

Comment: use this lib https://github.com/evernote/android-job it support all version

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html try this

Answer (score 0):

Use [Android-Job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) library provided by `evernote`. Its easy to use. It use either the `JobScheduler, GcmNetworkManager` or `AlarmManager`. Its works back to Ice Cream Sandwich. You don't have to check Android version manually this library will automatically choose the best for you. You can check [this](https://blog.evernote.com/tech/2015/10/26/unified-job-library-android/) blog post too.